# Apache CXF - Global HTTP Settings

Tags: cxf, apache-camel, fuseesb

Hi I have a Webservice exposed in FUSE ESB using Apache CXF endpoint. Client is required to pass the user name as password as below. Please advice How I can read this in my server from the Camel Exchange object.

```
((BindingProvider) serviceMnmtApi).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "admin");
((BindingProvider) serviceMnmtApi).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JBoss Fuse 6.1, you should be able to setup the the username and password from the endpoint URI option. It is addressed in [CAMEL-7145](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7145).

Comment: I am using JBOSS Fuse 6.0.  Can I get the changes here as well.

Comment: You may need to fill a patch request through the JBoss fuse support for it.